# node-watch ECONNRESET on network drive

Tags: node.js

I have a small app that uses node-watch to watch 2 network drives and moves files between them when a change occurs. But the network often goes down, how do I prevent ECONNRESET crashes?

The code:

```
watch(directories.SQL_XML_IN, {
    recursive: false,
    filter: function (name) {
        return /\.xml$/i.test(name);
    }
}, function (evt, name) {
    if (evt == 'update') {
        // move files
    }
});
```

And the error:

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: watch null ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1217:21)
```

Comment: the general strategy for node process is to let them fail and die and use a process manager to restart them.  Something like nodemon, forever, or pm2

Comment: So there's no good error handling for this? Doesn't sound very good, because this is used in an enterprise production environment

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var watcher = watch('...');

watcher.on('error', function(err) {
  // handle errors

  // close it if necessary
  watcher.close()
});
```

Comment: Please explain your code and why it could answer the question